# Copy a few columns from a table to another

Tags: mysql, insert, copy

Well, what I mean is I want to create a new table called 'personas2' with the dates of 3 columns from another table called 'personas' (that table has 5 columns, but I only need 3 of them), and, at the same time, I need insert the values of that 3 columns from 'personas' into 'personas2' where the value of one column 'cod_hospital' is 4.

This is what I did:

```
 use bd_hospital;
 create table personas2 (
 dni int PRIMARY KEY,
 apellidos varchar(50),
 funcion varchar(30))
select dni, apellidos, funcion from personas where cod_hospital=4;
```

It works, but I want to know if exists another way for that, I mean, create the table without add the columns for myself, something like:

```
insert into personas2 select dni, apellidos, funcion from personas where cod_hospital=4;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use create as select :

```
CREATE TABLE personas2 AS(
SELECT dni, apellidos, funcion
from personas
where cod_hospital=4)
```

Comment: That's it. That's what I need. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem @ilos28 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Create table personas2 like personas;
```

Which creates a table with the same profile, and then fill it with your query.

Comment: that's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: No, it's an answer, just not the answer.

Comment: In the beginning It was what I did, but I remember that there's another way simpler than that.

Answer (score -1):

We need to specify the columns in insert script

```
insert into person2(date1, date2, date3) 
select date1, date2, date3 from personas where cod_hospital=4;
```

Comment: That was what I tried, but It didn't work... at least like I need. But thanks for your answer.